# How to revert the file extension of all classes from .class to .java?

Tags: java, file, ide, git-bash

I am working on a Java carsharing console application using Eclipse IDE and GitBash. While working with GitBash, I accidentally renamed all the classes in my project from having a .java extension to having a .class extension. Now, when I try to open the classes in Eclipse, they are not recognized as Java classes and cannot be compiled. Is there a way to revert the file extension of all the classes back to .java in my project?
I tried to rename them back to manual but it didn't work.
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Y3Q.png)

I tried to rename them back to manual but it didn't work.
[when expanding the class and when expanding the java, nothing has changed] [image]

Comment: "I tried to rename them back to manual but it didn't work." - "didn't work" is never enough information. What exactly happened when you tried?

Comment: Yeah i add information about problem

Comment: The second picture is not java source code; it looks like the content of an actual class file. If that's the only instance of that particular .class file, then your java source is gone forever.

Comment: can't you restore the files from Git? If that image is the content of such a file, you did not just rename the `.java` files... in the image we see the result of compilation, a typical generated `.class` file - how exactly did you "*renamed all the classes*"?

Comment: You might be able to use the Eclipse "Restore from Local History..." option, or  maybe "Replace With > Local History..."

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information available it seems that you didn't rename the files, you actually compiled them to .class files. If you lost your source code you can try to recover it by using a Java Decompiler, which does the reverse that the Java compiler. From .class files it can try to create the equivalent source Java. Note that a decompiler does an approximate work and sometime it can not reconstruct the original, or may loose some details. Formatting and comments are always lost when decompiling.